# Smooth radial-gradient edge im stuck

Tags: html, css, user-interface, css-gradients

so I'm working on this UI and I've decided I want to try and animate it to pop out from the main portrait circle, my only problem is I cannot for the life of me get this radial-gradient to be smooth.

The entire issue comes from me wanting an inverted border-radius on the left-hand side so it matches up with the portrait circle when stationary. I saw a couple of different ways to do this, but I'm fairly amateur and figured this radial gradient seemed like the most simple way. However, now I'm left with this horrible jagged edge scooped side.

I've looked at different gradient styles instead of using circle and I tried wrapping my head around "Andreas Larsen's" "[easing linear gradients](https://css-tricks.com/easing-linear-gradients/)" post to no avail.

Here's a JSFiddle with only the necessary code showing the UI, if anyone could assist it would be more valuable to me than you know :)
https://jsfiddle.net/Infamoose/thj9305f/1/

**EDIT:** Ignore all the wonky bars and icon's, I am fixing that :P I'm just trying to set up the microphone icon in the radial-gradient section first.

```css
.positive {
    color: rgb(114, 204, 114);
}

.negative {
    color: rgb(224, 50, 50);
}

.tempbg {
    background: solid;
    background-color: rgb(0, 122, 204);
}

.portrait {
    background-color: rgb(219, 12, 12);
    position: absolute;
    top: 34px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 110px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.container {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.288);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 260px;
    height: 85px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0%;
    border-top-left-radius: 0%;
    z-index: 1;
}

#heal, #armor, #hunger, #thirst, #stamina, #voice {
}

#boxHeal, #boxArmor, #boxStamina, #boxHunger, #boxThirst, #boxVoice {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#heal {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    bottom: 68px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    float:left;
}

#armor {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    bottom: 56px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    float:left;
}

#hunger {
    position: absolute;
    left: 62px;
    bottom: 32px;
    width: 107.5px;
    height: 10px;
}

.iconhunger {
    position: relative;
    left: -40px;
    bottom: 10px;
    z-index: 3;
    align-content: left;
 }

#thirst {
    position: absolute;
    left: 22px;
    bottom: 61px;
    width: 107.5px;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    float:left;
}

.iconthirst {
    position: relative;
    left: 0.5px;
    bottom: -34px;
    z-index: 3;
    align-content: left;
 }

#stamina {
    position: absolute;
    left: 62.5px;
    bottom: 11px;
    width: 107.5px;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    float:left;
}

.iconstamina {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    align-content: left;
    left: -20px;
    bottom: 6px;
 }

#voice {
    position: absolute;
    left: 148.5px;
    bottom: -500px;
    width: 107.5px;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    float:left;
}

.fa-microphone {
    position: inherit;
    z-index: 3;
    left: 57px;
    bottom: 525.5px;
    font-size: 38;
 }

.fa-microphonebg {
    position: absolute;
    top: -575px;
    left: -10px;
    width: 121px;
    height: 85px;
    background-image:
  radial-gradient(circle at 0% 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50px, #fff 50px);
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
    z-index: 2;
}

#boxHeal {
    background: rgb(97, 191, 92);
    border: solid 0.3px rgb(97, 191, 92);
    border-radius: 30px;
}

#boxArmor {
    background: rgb(96, 136, 220);
    border: solid 0.3px rgb(96, 136, 220);
    border-radius: 30px;
}

#boxHunger {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    position: absolute;
    left: -10;
    bottom: 9.7px;
    border: solid 0.3px #ffffff;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

#boxThirst {
    background:rgb(255, 255, 255);
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    bottom: -32;
    border: solid 0.3px #ffffff;
    border-radius: 30px;

}

#boxStamina {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
    bottom: 5px;
    border: solid 0.3px #ffffff;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

#boxVoice {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    position: absolute;
    left: -96px;
    bottom: -4px;
    border: solid 0.3px #ffffff;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

#boxVoice.active {
    background: rgb(235, 36, 39);
}

.position {
    font-family: "gta-ui", Verdana, Tahoma;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0.35%;
    left: 16%;
    text-shadow: -1px 1px 2px #000, 1px 1px 2px #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px -1px 0 #000;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.seperator {
    color: rgb(224, 50, 50);
}

.seperator2 {
    color: rgb(240, 200, 80);
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="css/icono.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://icono-49d6.kxcdn.com/icono.min.css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3f31cfc768.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body class="tempbg">
        <div class="portrait">
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="heal">
                <div id="boxHeal"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="armor">
                <div id="boxArmor"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="hunger">
                    <svg class="iconhunger" width="36" height="12" viewBox="0 0 14 12" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <g clip-path="url(#clip0)">
                        <path d="M9.44096 7.09788L12.0944 4.62314C13.9855 2.86906 14.0734 1.25095 13.9708 0.462298C13.9561 0.407908 13.9268 0.353518 13.8828 0.312725C13.7656 0.203945 13.5897 0.203945 13.4724 0.312725L12.6954 1.03339L2.94672 10.0893C2.62421 10.3885 2.62421 10.8916 2.94672 11.1907C3.26923 11.4899 3.81164 11.4899 4.13415 11.1907L4.33939 10.946C4.70588 10.4973 6.58232 7.98172 6.86086 7.58739C6.97813 7.42422 7.09541 7.32904 7.18337 7.28825C7.32997 7.23386 7.44724 7.30185 7.44724 7.30185C8.09227 7.65538 8.91321 7.58739 9.44096 7.09788Z" fill="white"/>
                        <path d="M4.95508 6.20047C5.49749 5.9965 5.86398 6.17327 6.09854 6.36364L6.86084 5.65657C6.65561 5.43901 6.46503 5.08547 6.68493 4.59596C6.99278 3.90249 7.242 3.45377 6.17184 2.37957C5.131 1.29176 3.4598 0.285548 2.68283 0.0679876C2.50692 0.027195 2.331 0 2.19906 0C2.1844 0 2.1844 0 2.16974 0C2.12577 0 2.09645 0.0135975 2.06713 0.0407925C1.99383 0.10878 1.99383 0.21756 2.06713 0.27195L4.70587 2.7195C4.83781 2.84188 4.83781 3.04584 4.70587 3.18182C4.57393 3.3042 4.35404 3.3042 4.20744 3.18182L3.89959 2.89627L3.21058 2.25719C2.69749 1.78127 2.36032 1.46853 2.03781 1.22378C1.26084 0.625486 0.95299 0.611888 0.95299 0.611888C0.95299 0.611888 0.835713 0.598291 0.733095 0.679876C0.645137 0.775058 0.659797 0.883838 0.659797 0.883838C0.659797 0.883838 0.674456 1.16939 1.33414 1.90365C1.59802 2.2028 1.93519 2.51554 2.44828 2.99145L3.13728 3.63054L3.44514 3.91608C3.57707 4.03846 3.57707 4.24242 3.44514 4.3784C3.3132 4.50078 3.0933 4.50078 2.94671 4.3784L0.307964 1.93085C0.234666 1.86286 0.117388 1.86286 0.0587496 1.93085C0.0294302 1.95804 0.0147705 1.98524 0.0147705 2.02603C0.0147705 2.02603 0.0147705 2.03963 0.0147705 2.05322C0.0147705 2.1756 0.0440899 2.33877 0.0880689 2.50194C0.307964 3.22261 1.40744 4.75913 2.58022 5.75175C3.73833 6.71717 4.20744 6.48601 4.95508 6.20047Z" fill="white"/>
                        <path d="M9.51434 7.737C9.1625 7.95456 8.73737 8.07694 8.29758 8.07694C8.03371 8.07694 7.78449 8.03614 7.53528 7.95456L10.6138 11.3539C11.0683 11.7619 11.7866 11.7619 12.2264 11.3539C12.6662 10.946 12.6662 10.2661 12.2264 9.85821L9.51434 7.737Z" fill="white"/>
                        </g>
                        </svg> 
                <div id="boxHunger">                           
            </div>
        </div>
            <div id="thirst">
                    <svg class="iconthirst" width="36" height="14" viewBox="0 0 8 12" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M3.74196 0.100677C3.72525 0.0356591 3.65843 -0.013104 3.57491 0.00315034C3.52479 0.0194047 3.49138 0.0519134 3.47467 0.100677C2.9067 4.55437 0 5.46462 0 8.5692C0.0501155 10.5035 1.68722 12.0476 3.67514 11.9989C5.61294 11.9664 7.16652 10.4385 7.19993 8.5692C7.21663 5.48087 4.30993 4.55437 3.74196 0.100677ZM3.19069 5.02575C3.15728 5.15579 3.10716 5.30207 3.07375 5.44836C2.82317 6.34235 2.52248 7.35013 2.52248 8.52044C2.52248 9.15436 2.13826 9.38192 1.77075 9.38192C1.35312 9.38192 1.01902 9.05683 1.01902 8.65048C1.01902 7.26885 1.70393 6.35861 2.30531 5.56215C2.48907 5.31833 2.67283 5.07451 2.82317 4.84695C2.88999 4.74943 3.00693 4.73317 3.10716 4.79819C3.12387 4.81444 3.14057 4.8307 3.15728 4.84695C3.19069 4.89572 3.20739 4.96073 3.19069 5.02575Z" fill="white"/>
                        </svg>
                <div id="boxThirst"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="stamina">
                    <svg class="iconstamina" width="36" height="12" viewBox="0 0 21 8" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M2 0H16C17.1046 0 18 0.89543 18 2V5.71428C18 6.81885 17.1046 7.71429 16 7.71429H2C0.895431 7.71429 0 6.81886 0 5.71429V2C0 0.895433 0.895429 0 2 0ZM2 1C1.44772 1 1 1.44772 1 2V5.71429C1 6.26657 1.44772 6.71429 2 6.71429H16C16.5523 6.71429 17 6.26657 17 5.71428V2C17 1.44772 16.5523 1 16 1H2ZM19.2857 2.54286C19.2857 2.32194 19.4648 2.14286 19.6857 2.14286C19.9066 2.14286 20.0857 2.32194 20.0857 2.54286V5.17143C20.0857 5.39234 19.9066 5.57143 19.6857 5.57143C19.4648 5.57143 19.2857 5.39234 19.2857 5.17143V2.54286ZM3.14286 2.14286C2.59057 2.14286 2.14286 2.59057 2.14286 3.14286V4.57143C2.14286 5.12371 2.59057 5.57143 3.14286 5.57143H9.14286C9.69514 5.57143 10.1429 5.12371 10.1429 4.57143V3.14286C10.1429 2.59057 9.69514 2.14286 9.14286 2.14286H3.14286Z" fill="white"/>
                        </svg>
                <div id="boxStamina"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="voice">
                <div class="fa-microphonebg">
                    </div>
                    <i class="fas fa-microphone"></i>                   
                <div id="boxVoice"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: simply avoid the same value for colors, add 1px to the last one : https://jsfiddle.net/xcw348hn/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your issue is right here:

```
radial-gradient(circle at 0% 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50px, #fff 50px);
```

you need a pixel of separation between the transparent layer (`rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)`)and the white layer (`#fff`) for this gradual curve to work:

```
radial-gradient(circle at 0% 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50px, #fff 51px);
```

Should fix your issue. Radial gradients are tricky especially when you try to make some out-of-the-box shapes with them. :)

Comment: I tell you what, this made my day. :') 

I totally didn't just spend around 2-3 hours trying to figure out easing linear gradients and different ways of smoothing gradients / inverting border-radius for the fix to simply be 1px change.

Thank very much, you've at least saved me another few hours because I probably would have continued to miss the simple fix

Comment: I applaud you for sticking with it! Ive been writing in css for years and radial gradients still make me pull out my hair sometimes! Looks like Temani Afif also discovered the solution in your comments. Make sure to give his comment an upvote as well. :)

Comment: I've been writing in CSS for about 2 weeks and I'm already pulling my hair out so the applause is all yours :P Now I've just gotta figure out keyframes and make this side-bar thing only slide out and show when a button is pressed.

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle for an implementation: its really rough, but i think it would be a good starting place: https://jsfiddle.net/webnetvn/p26nvy8j/43/

Comment: Note that a change was made to .portrait changing from position:absolute to position:fixed to prevent it moving off screen, the rest has been wrapped into some new html elements using a checkbox as a toggle to do this without javascript (which is how i like all things, except nodejs) and the accompanying CSS has been added to the bottom :)

Comment: You're a wizard. I've just managed to fix all the positioning of everything but whenever I put it into jsfiddle it all messes up again so not sure what's going on there. The checkbox is a smart idea, I will, however, have to include javascript and a keypress function as it's going into a game. Thank you so much for giving me a direction and something to work with. Is there a private messaging alternative I could contact you on incase I get stuck again instead of filling up this thread with unrelated information? If not it's no problem, I'll probably end up making a new thread :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196745/discussion-between-infamoose-and-jl-griffin).